# Label DataTemplate depending on selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to use different DataTemplates depending on what type of item is selected in a TreeView

**XAML**

```
<TreeView Name="SourceDocumentsList" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceDocuments}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type docom:Document}" ItemsSource="{Binding Blocks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Filename}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
<Label Name="DescriptionLabel"
       DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SourceDocumentsList, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <Label.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DocumentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type docom:Document}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Label.Resources>
</Label>
```

In my understanding, the `Label` will display the `Description` property only if a `Document`-type item is selected in the TreeView. Unfortunately, that's not the case. It displays nothing, no matter what I select in the TreeView.

The TreeView itself works just fine with my existing model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide a key, this means the Template cannot be applied implicitly.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lst"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=lst, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <Label.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Class1}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Label.Resources>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above code works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTemplateSelector class to apply different data template at run time.

[DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

Comment: But why do I need that? The DataTemplate of the TreeView works without a selector, too?